# network solutions image width for mobile and desktop view

Tags: html, css

HELP.ive been searching a lot about how to code an image where it can overlap the margins of the page in network solutions.im not that good yet but believe me i spent nights already for trial and error and im not that good yet especially in css.and im not using mobile view in the website im making but is it possible that if there is a code for the width of the image like it will widen from both ends of screen but it will automatically resize to fit in mobile view pleas sombedy help this is my last coding that didnt work.Please help me

**My tried code:**

```
#responsive-image {  width: 100%;  height: auto; } 
<img src="http://users.neo.registeredsite.com/4/2/5/19587524/assets/qwertyuiop1.jpg" id="responsive-image" />
```

PICTURE OF WHAT I WANT TO HAPPEN:
[image]

Comment: can you include screen shot of your problem?

Comment: hi nihal i already edited my post and added an example of what id like to happen hope u can help me

Comment: width 100% works fine!

Comment: at exactly which view you are getting problem?

Comment: yeah i tried that at first but what happens is it does not fully occupy both ends of the page because of probably the margins built in from network solutions.and when i drag it to overlap a little from the margin the mobile view gets distorted.ill try the code that u given me awhile ago i really appreciate and hope that u can help me nihal.

Comment: what is network solution which you are using? is that css or what?

Comment: its like a web hosting where u can make a website and they already have templates.so for this one they have like this snippet where you can insert codes and thats where im placing the codes

Comment: can you send me link of that?

Comment: https://www.networksolutions.com/index.jsp     thats the website.and i can add snippets to it.im trying to put in the code that u gave me

Answer (score 0):

Always use img tag inside div in the any html project.

```css
div{
width:100%;
}
#responsive-image {  width: inherit;  height: auto; }
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<div>
<img src="http://users.neo.registeredsite.com/4/2/5/19587524/assets/qwertyuiop1.jpg" id="responsive-image" /></div>
```

Comment: [http://forums.networksolutions.com/designing-your-storefront-f26-css-stylesheets-t1478.html](http://forums.networksolutions.com/designing-your-storefront-f26-css-stylesheets-t1478.html)

Comment: Go to Themes/theme_name/css folder, and upload there. in network solution

Comment: ok nihal i will and thanks for helping me i hope i could make it

Comment: hey nihal thanks man.i was able to make it.i have put an image that never changes its size even if you zoom it on desktop and same with mobile view it auto resize itself.thanks for helping man i never knew i could access the file manager cause i thought i can only use the snippets for coding and now i was able to upload stylesheets on the website thanks bro thumbs up to you

Comment: did you go through that forum? Themes/theme_name/css folder

Comment: or used some other solution?

Comment: i used some other solution and i just put the codes on the header and body of the page on file manager.

Comment: i was frustated because i thought theres no way i can access the file manager of the webmaker and that all i have to do is drag and drop and use html for snippets.thanks for helping me find it

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, you want to make your image cover the full width of webpage.
Use 100vh instead of 100%, this will make your width equal to 100% of viewport width

```
#responsive-image {  width: 100vh;  height: auto; } 
<img src="http://users.neo.registeredsite.com/4/2/5/19587524/assets/qwertyuiop1.jpg" id="responsive-image" />
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: i tried to use the code but as i drag to widen the snippet the picture seems to have a permanent size and doesnt resize

Comment: Can you tag your actual code, without it, it seems impossible to guess what is going on!

Comment: i already got it.i was able to access the file manager and was able to do so thanks man